# Regarding the differences among these four regular expressions with minor differences

Tags: regex, perl

When learning regular expressions, I once saw the following four examples. How can I understand their differences?

```
/ABC (?i:s) XYZ/
/ABC (?x: [A-Z] \.?  \s )?XYZ/
/ABC (?ix: [A-Z] \.?  \s )?XYZ/
/ABC (?x-i: [A-Z] \.?  \s )?XYZ/i
```

What do the `i` and `x` flags mean?

Comment: Which part do you not understand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are very straightforward. A quick look at the [documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) would answer your questions. You might also find [YAPE::Regex::Explain](http://search.perl.org/perldoc?YAPE%3a%3aRegex%3a%3aExplain) useful.

```
$ perl -MYAPE::Regex::Explain -e'
   print YAPE::Regex::Explain->new($_)->explain
      for 
         qr/ABC (?i:s) XYZ/,
         qr/ABC (?x: [A-Z] \.?  \s )?XYZ/,
         qr/ABC (?ix: [A-Z] \.?  \s )?XYZ/,
         qr/ABC (?x-i: [A-Z] \.?  \s )?XYZ/i;
'
```

```
The regular expression:

(?-imsx:ABC (?i:s) XYZ)

matches as follows:

NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
(?-imsx:                 group, but do not capture (case-sensitive)
                         (with ^ and $ matching normally) (with . not
                         matching \n) (matching whitespace and #
                         normally):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  ABC                      'ABC '
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?i:                     group, but do not capture (case-
                           insensitive) (with ^ and $ matching
                           normally) (with . not matching \n)
                           (matching whitespace and # normally):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    s                        's'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
   XYZ                     ' XYZ'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
)                        end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

```
The regular expression:

(?-imsx:ABC (?x: [A-Z] \.?  \s )?XYZ)

matches as follows:

NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
(?-imsx:                 group, but do not capture (case-sensitive)
                         (with ^ and $ matching normally) (with . not
                         matching \n) (matching whitespace and #
                         normally):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  ABC                      'ABC '
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?x:                     group, but do not capture (disregarding
                           whitespace and comments) (case-sensitive)
                           (with ^ and $ matching normally) (with .
                           not matching \n) (optional (matching the
                           most amount possible)):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [A-Z]                    any character of: 'A' to 'Z'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \.?                      '.' (optional (matching the most amount
                             possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \s                       whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )?                       end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  XYZ                      'XYZ'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
)                        end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

```
The regular expression:

(?-imsx:ABC (?ix: [A-Z] \.?  \s )?XYZ)

matches as follows:

NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
(?-imsx:                 group, but do not capture (case-sensitive)
                         (with ^ and $ matching normally) (with . not
                         matching \n) (matching whitespace and #
                         normally):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  ABC                      'ABC '
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?ix:                    group, but do not capture (case-
                           insensitive) (disregarding whitespace and
                           comments) (with ^ and $ matching normally)
                           (with . not matching \n) (optional
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [A-Z]                    any character of: 'A' to 'Z'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \.?                      '.' (optional (matching the most amount
                             possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \s                       whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )?                       end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  XYZ                      'XYZ'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
)                        end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

```
The regular expression:

(?i-msx:ABC (?x-i: [A-Z] \.?  \s )?XYZ)

matches as follows:

NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
(?i-msx:                 group, but do not capture (case-insensitive)
                         (with ^ and $ matching normally) (with . not
                         matching \n) (matching whitespace and #
                         normally):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  ABC                      'ABC '
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?x-i:                   group, but do not capture (disregarding
                           whitespace and comments) (case-sensitive)
                           (with ^ and $ matching normally) (with .
                           not matching \n) (optional (matching the
                           most amount possible)):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [A-Z]                    any character of: 'A' to 'Z'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \.?                      '.' (optional (matching the most amount
                             possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \s                       whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )?                       end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  XYZ                      'XYZ'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
)                        end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score -1):

`/`*expr*`/`*flags* applies *flags* to *expr*.

`(?`*flags*`:`subexpr`)` applies *flags* to *subexpr*.

`i` sets to ignore case, `x` sets to ignore whitespaces in the regexp body.

More detailed information is available on [www.regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html).

Comment: Oh, and `-i` in *(?:flags)* turns case-sensitive matching on (disables `/i`).

Comment: @yarek, we try to maintain a certain level of civility here at SO, not to mention helpfulness.  Terse, minimalist answers are discouraged, and blatantly rude remarks like RTFM and LMGTFY are specifically forbidden.